# vbTrue is not True

Tags: excel, vba, userform

The Excel constant "True" evaluates to True and the constant "vbTrue" evaluates to -1. I've always treated these as interchangeable in VBA code, but it's not so.  One place where these two constants produce different results is in setting CheckBoxes. Setting the CheckBox.value to True produces the expected result, but setting it to vbTrue leaves the CheckBox in a TripleState.

```
Sub setCkBox1()
       CheckBox1.TripleState = False
       CheckBox1.Value = vbTrue   '<<<< the check mark is dimmed to show TripleState is True
       Debug.Print CheckBox1.TripleState: Stop  '<<<< even though it won't admit it

       CheckBox1.Value = True  '<<<< check mark is not dimmed

End Sub
```

So my question is, where else in VBA are these two constants not interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`True` is a Boolean, `vbTrue` is a Long.  They are not interchangeable anywhere that Booleans and Longs are not interchangeable.

Comment: vbTrue is a Constant (from the Tristate group), where did you see it was a `long`?

Comment: Actually, it's an Enum member from TriState, IIRC.  But either way, constants (and Enum members) have a datatype too.  Look at the return string from `TypeName(vbTrue)` to see this.